# Moment : Compare two dates wrong result

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I've trying to compare two dates inside in a UI-GRID, at the end I have two dates in the right format but it is not working, always give me a false result.

The code is the following:

```
filters: [{
    condition: function (term, value) {
        if (!term) return true;
        var valueDate = moment.utc(value).format(CONST.LANGUAJE.dateformat);
        var replaced = term.replace(/\\/g, '');
        var termDate = moment.utc(replaced, CONST.LANGUAJE.dateformat).format(CONST.LANGUAJE.dateformat); // moment(replaced).format(CONST.LANGUAJE.dateformat); // new Date(replaced);
        console.log('valueDate >= termDate: ' + valueDate + '>=' + termDate + ' moment result: ' + moment(valueDate).isAfter(termDate));
        return moment(valueDate).isAfter(termDate); // valueDate >= termDate;
    },
    placeholder: 'greatter than'
},
```

In the console log I have this:

```
valueDate >= termDate: 16/09/2022>=23/01/2011 moment result: false
woControllerPreventive.js:97 valueDate >= termDate: 16/09/2025>=23/01/2011 
moment result: false
woControllerPreventive.js:97 valueDate >= termDate: 16/09/2020>=23/01/2011 
moment result: false
woControllerPreventive.js:97 valueDate >= termDate: 16/11/2010>=23/01/2011 
moment result: false
woControllerPreventive.js:97 valueDate >= termDate: 16/09/2022>=23/01/2011 
moment result: false
woControllerPreventive.js:97 valueDate >= termDate: 16/09/2021>=23/01/2011 
moment result: false
4woControllerPreventive.js:97 valueDate >= termDate: 16/09/2020>=23/01/2011 
moment result: false
3woControllerPreventive.js:97 valueDate >= termDate: 16/09/2019>=23/01/2011 
moment result: false
```

Obviosuly 16/09/2025>=23/01/2011 this is true, but I don't konw why is not working.

Comment: What makes you think that moment('16/09/2025') will interpret 16 as day, 09 as month and 2025 as year? Does the documentation (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) say that it supports that format? What does the documentation (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) say about parsing dates? Everything is really much, much easier once you have read the documentation. Read it.

Comment: I've read the documentation and all of my dates are formating as: 'DD-MM-YYYY' in my country is the way to read dates. Before asking I try to resolve by myself... Thanks.

Comment: But moment(string) doesn't parse a string as it's formatted in your country. It parses a string as specified in the documentation. And the supported formats do NOT include DD/MM/YYYY. You need to pass an explicit format to do that, once again, as explained in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. All works perfectly. I'm not a navite English speaker and some times I miss some aspects of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Only works with the format 
`moment('2010-10-20').isAfter('2010-10-19'); // true`

See: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/